# select only columns which are having at least one non-zero rows. SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

currently, I have a table like below

```
+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|  country   | 0-1 days | 1-2 days | 2-3 days | 3-4 days | 4-5 days | 5-6 days | 6-7 days | 7-8 days | 8-9 days | 9-10 days | >10 days |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| country_1  |        1 |       56 |        4 |        6 |        3 |        2 |        0 |        0 |        0 |         0 |        0 |
| country_2  |        1 |        1 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |         0 |        0 |
| country_3  |        1 |        4 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |         0 |        0 |
| country_4  |        1 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |         0 |        0 |
| country_5  |        1 |        3 |        0 |        1 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |         0 |        0 |
| country_6  |        1 |       11 |        2 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |         0 |        0 |
| country_7  |        1 |       31 |        9 |        4 |        2 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        0 |         0 |        0 |
| country_8  |        1 |       15 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |         0 |        0 |
| country_9  |        1 |       13 |        2 |        3 |        0 |        0 |        1 |        0 |        0 |         0 |        0 |
| country_10 |        1 |        2 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        0 |         0 |        0 |
| country_11 |        1 |        5 |        1 |        0 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |         0 |        0 |
| country_12 |        1 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |         0 |        0 |
| country_13 |        1 |        5 |        1 |        1 |        0 |        1 |        0 |        0 |        0 |         0 |        0 |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

I would like to exclude all the columns which are having all zero values.
So, I am expecting output not to have

1. 7-8 days
2. 8-9 days
3. 9-10 days
4. >10 days

Using SQL Server 2016.

**Edit**
If I have extra column, like `country` with as `primary key`. How to use `dynamic sql` to select only columns which are not zeros?

Comment: You will need to use `Dynamic SQL` as the columns in the result set of your query might change

Comment: Seems like you should be normalising your data; that's the *real* problem here.

Comment: Is this `TABLE` an actual table or it is just an intermediary result of another query ?

Comment: This is my source table getting populated in server. @Squirrel

Comment: As others commented. You should really consider normalize it

Comment: Then you should really normalisi it then, @tharun-reddy . You're table doesn't even appear to have some kind of key, which is means there nothing to identify what each row represents.

Answer (score 0):

refer to below sample scripts

first, you will need to find the list of columns name with non-zero. After that, use dynamic query to select from your table

```
create table sample_table
(
    ID  int identity,
    col1    int,
    col2    int,
    col3    int
)

insert into sample_table (col1, col2, col3)
values  (1, 12, 0),
    (1,  0, 0),
    (1, 13, 0),
    (1, 14, 0),
    (1, 0, 0)

declare @cols   nvarchar(max),
        @sql    nvarchar(max)

select  @cols   =
        case    when    sum(case when col1 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) <> 0
        then    ',col1'
        else    ''
        end
+       case    when    sum(case when col2 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) <> 0
        then    ',col2'
        else    ''
        end 
+       case    when    sum(case when col3 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) <> 0
        then    ',col3'
        else    ''
        end 
from    sample_table

select  @sql    = 'SELECT ID' + @cols + ' '
                + 'FROM sample_table'

exec    sp_executesql   @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Cursor` or `while` loop to get the column detail and dynamically build nonzero-sum columns.

try the following:

```
create table test_tab (country varchar(100) ,[0-1 days] int,[1-2 days] int,[2-3 days] int,[3-4 days] int,[4-5 days] int,[5-6 days] int,[6-7 days] int,[7-8 days] int,[8-9 days] int,[9-10 days] int,[>10 days] int)
insert into test_tab select 'country_1' ,       1,      56,       4,       6,       3,       2,       0,       0,       0,        0,       0
insert into test_tab select 'country_2' ,       1,       1,       1,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,        0,       0
insert into test_tab select 'country_3' ,       1,       4,       1,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,        0,       0
insert into test_tab select 'country_4' ,       1,       1,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,        0,       0
insert into test_tab select 'country_5' ,       1,       3,       0,       1,       1,       0,       0,       0,       0,        0,       0
insert into test_tab select 'country_6' ,       1,      11,       2,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,        0,       0
insert into test_tab select 'country_7' ,       1,      31,       9,       4,       2,       1,       0,       0,       0,        0,       0
insert into test_tab select 'country_8' ,       1,      15,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,        0,       0
insert into test_tab select 'country_9' ,       1,      13,       2,       3,       0,       0,       1,       0,       0,        0,       0
insert into test_tab select 'country_10',       1,       2,       0,       0,       0,       1,       0,       0,       0,        0,       0
insert into test_tab select 'country_11',       1,       5,       1,       0,       1,       0,       0,       0,       0,        0,       0
insert into test_tab select 'country_12',       1,       1,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,       0,        0,       0
insert into test_tab select 'country_13',       1,       5,       1,       1,       0,       1,       0,       0,       0,        0,       0

select * from dbname.schemaname.test_tab

declare @non_zero_columns varchar(max) = ''

declare cur cursor fast_forward for
select name from dbname.sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('dbo.test_tab') and name like '%days'   --hope there is some kind of pattern

declare @col_name sysname
declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @result int

open cur
fetch next from cur into @col_name

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @query = 'set @result = (select sum('+quotename(@col_name)+') from dbname.schemaname.test_tab)'
    exec sp_executesql @query, N'@result int out', @result out

    if (@result <> 0)
        set @non_zero_columns = @non_zero_columns + ',' + quotename(@col_name)

    fetch next from cur into @col_name
end

close cur
deallocate cur

declare @final_dynamic_sql varchar(max) = 'select country '+@non_zero_columns+' from dbname.schemaname.test_tab'

print (@final_dynamic_sql)
exec (@final_dynamic_sql)
```

HTH!